# Filter array with filter() and includes()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I have

```
const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(pets.filter((pet) => !pet.includes('cat', 'dog')));
```

Expected output

```
["bat"]
```

Actual Output

```
["dog", "bat"]
```

This is just an example. In my real code, I'm doing a delete action to my global state (useContext, useReducer).

```
convocatorias: state.convocatorias.filter(
    (convocatoria) => !convocatoria._id.includes(action.payload)
),
```

`action.payload` is an array of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.includes() takes one argument, you meant:

```js
const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(pets.filter((pet) => !['cat', 'dog'].includes(pet)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse your logic, like so:

```js
pets.filter(pet => ['cat', 'dog'].includes(pet))
```

Answer (score 1):

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) determine whether an array includes certain value. In your case `pet` is not an array but it is the element which is currently under iteration.

Secondly `includes` with two parameters like `includes('cat', 'dog')` means search `cat` from array index 'dog'. Array index are number based so `includes('cat', 'dog')` will not make any sense

```js
const excludedVals = ['cat', 'dog'];
const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(pets.filter((pet) => !excludedVals.includes(pet)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Includes() takes in one parameter but you have the alternative of using an && conditional or regex.

```js
const pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(pets.filter((pet) => !pet.includes('cat') && !pet.includes('dog')));

console.log(pets.filter((pet) => !(new RegExp(/(cat|dog)/).test(pet))))
```